# Can I make my Ubuntu make sounds when I press Caps Lock etc.?

Tags: 12.04, sound, keyboard

On the computer upstairs we have an option to make the computer make a sound when we press Caps Lock, Number Lock and Scroll Lock. Is there a way to do this on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Yes this is possible, I quite forgot how. Let me get back to this.

Comment: Cool. Hope u can work it out!

Comment: This is kinda the answer you want. I will keep looking: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/get-caps-num-scroll-lock-keys-notifyosd.html

Comment: Ok. Can you give me something un-terminal related?

Comment: I think you have to use terminal. But this looks even easier:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11575559&postcount=2
What is the problem with terminal?

Comment: It's just I don't want something going wrong. I don't want to go through the hassle of installing ubuntu via usb if it does go wrong. And i'm not used to linux

Comment: as long as you don't type anything else then the given commands, nothing will go wrong. But look at the last link I gave you, that one is rather easy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6883/discussion-between-nerof61-and-dr-bunsen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I got this to work with xbindkeys.

We will use Beep as notification sound.

To install Beep:

```
sudo apt-get install beep
```

It is necessary to enable the speaker in recent versions.

```
modprobe pcspkr
```

Ok, now for the notification script:
First make a new file, and save it as notification.sh.

Insert this piece of script(smallest script ever?):

```
beep
```

and save it.
Place it somewhere safe, for this little "tut" I will place it in /home/notification/
Now we need xbindkeys:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Once it is installed, go to your home folder, and make a new file named:".xbindkeysrc".
This file is required for xbindkeys, without, it doesn't function.
Open this file with a text editor.

Now we do need the keynumbers xbindkeys requires.
To get those, open terminal, and enter:

```
xbindkeys -k
```

A windows will popup, and then you are to press the key you want the code from, eg. Capslock.

You will see something like:

> in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key. "NoCommand"
>       m:0x2 + c:66
>       Caps_Lock

Now, we only need the `m:0x2 + c:66` part(might be different for you).
Write those down(in a text editor or something) and repeat the process until you got all your keys.

Now, remember the xbindkeysrc we opened in the texteditor? We are going to add the following:

```
"bash /home/notification/notification.sh"
```

This line will tell what the xbindkeys has to do when certain keys are pressed.
The next line we will add is the keycode(s), like this:

```
m:0x2 + c:66
```

if you want the same thing to happen with multiple keys, you must separate the keys, like this:

```
m:0x2 + c:66 || m:0x3 + c:67
```

The `||` means OR, this is not relevant for you.

A logout/login could be necessary to map the beep to the Caps Lock (for example).

I hope that this guide was useful for you and others.

Comment: I use xbindkeys, and by installing `xbindkeys-config` as well as `xbindkeys` there is no need for `xbindkeysrc` ... `xbindkeysrc` provides an easy to use GUI interface. Setting up the shortcut keys is particularly easy; there is no need to deal directly with all the ` m:0x3 + c:67` *stuff*.  `xbindkeys` is also useful in that you have more control over the modifier keys than does the default Keyboard Shortcuts app, though that app is quite good enough unless you are a keyboard shortcuts junkie (like me).

Comment: O, I didn't know that, but I do prefer knowing that code is actually used. I will update my answer, thanks.