# Beep on caps and num lock not working

Tags: sound, keyboard, pulseaudio, speakers

I've activated the beep when you press caps and num lock, but it is not working (I mean there's no sound when you press them).

My guess is that it tries to use the motherboard tiny built in speaker, and for some reason it won't work. (I don't know how is it called, that little speaker that usually comes embedded in your motherboard that makes some simple sounds, independently of your "normal" music speakers).

**Is there a way to set those keys sounds to use the normal speakers?** Just as if it were multimedia? I mean as any other sound in the computer, using the normal speakers.

Sorry about the weird explanation. My english isn't that good and I am trying to be clear on what I mean. Any edit in order to be clearer is very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not clear to me whether the original feature was meant to invoke the "bell" on the mainboard speaker, or use the desktop audio system. But this feature seems to have been broken in Ubuntu for several years. I just checked it with a Ubuntu 14.04 live CD and it definitely still does not work.

Its a shame, as this feature would not only be useful for people with accessibility needs, but for everyone; after all its easy to accidentally bump the Caps Lock key without noticing it.

The caps lock indicator light on most keyboards is a piddly little thing at the opposite end of the keyboard (really clever!), and on some laptops it is absent or is a micro-LED tucked under the lip of the laptop so you have to hold it up to eye-level to see the damn thing (there should be a special hell for the people who designed that 'feature').

There are various bug reports about this issue, none of which seem to have received any serious attention. Pretty disappointing, when Windows provides this feature but Ubuntu can't be bothered.

There is a "fix" mentioned here: "[Can I make my Ubuntu make sounds when I press Caps Lock etc.?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233970/can-i-make-my-ubuntu-make-sounds-when-i-press-caps-lock-etc)" (I have not reproduced the content of that article as its rather long). I have not yet tried that suggestion.